# condition if element is in list - ValueError, the true value is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get all elements in pandas dataframe that are in a list

```
l = ['a','b']

df[df['col1'] in l]
```

returns `ValueError`.
Why?

Comment: The syntax is just wrong. It may make sense in English to read `df['col1'] in l` but it doesn't make sense in _Python_. I'd suggest you post a [mcve] so we know what you really expect in the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if items in a dataframe/column are in a list, instead `x in y`, use `x.isin(y)`:

```
df[df['col1'].isin(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

On a wild guess, I assume you probably need [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
>>> df[np.isin(df['col1'], l)]
```